# Union two List<T> and filter out duplicates using EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, union

I have two `List<T>` objects with the same `T` object from two different data source and would like to union the two `List<T>` object into one `List<T>` object and filter out duplicates.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public List<MyClass> MyMethod(List<MyClass> ListA, List<MyClass> ListB)
{
    //would like to union ListA and ListB and filter out any duplicates by ID from ListB that are in ListA 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489258/linq-distinct-on-a-particular-property) by Jon skeet to remove duplicates.

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>
    (this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
{
    HashSet<TKey> seenKeys = new HashSet<TKey>();
    foreach (TSource element in source)
    {
        if (seenKeys.Add(keySelector(element)))
        {
            yield return element;
        }
    }
}
```

And then

```
public List<MyClass> MyMethod(List<MyClass> ListA, List<MyClass> ListB)
{
    return ListA.Union(ListB).DistinctBy(x => x.ID).ToList();
}
```

Comment: This is also included in Jon's MoreLinq library - https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/

Answer (score 3):

Maybe an easier pure-LINQ solution:

I used concat because anyway the GroupBy will remove all duplicates

```
    public List<MyClass> MyMethod(IEnumerable<MyClass> A, IEnumerable<MyClass> B)
    {
        return A.Concat(B).GroupBy(x => x.ID).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
public List<MyClass> MyMethod(List<MyClass> ListA, List<MyClass> ListB)
{
    return (ListA.Union(ListB)).GroupBy(x=>x.ID)
                               .Select(gr=>new MyClass { 
                                   ID=gr.Key, 
                                   Name=gr.Select(x=>x.Name).First()})
                               .ToLIst();
}
```

Initially we take the union of the two lists. Then we group by the result by the `ID` and we pick only the first item of each group.